# How to fix problem with parser.add_argument

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to add the metavar information to a particular command line argument, and when I add in information within brackets, Python throws an error.

If I have the 'Bq' in the brackets, it gives an error. If I have no brackets (or nothing between them), I do not get an error.

```
parser.add_argument("--dispensed_activity", dest="aDActivity", type=int,  action="store", required=True, metavar="<amount dispensed (Bq)>", help="Activity dispensed (Bq)")
```

The error stack is:

```
File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 1730, in parse_args
args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)

File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 1762, in parse_known_args
namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)

File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 1997, in _parse_known_args
', '.join(required_actions))

File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 2387, in error
self.print_usage(_sys.stderr)

File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 2357, in print_usage
self._print_message(self.format_usage(), file)

File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 2323, in format_usage
return formatter.format_help()

File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 282, in format_help
help = self._root_section.format_help()

File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 213, in format_help
item_help = join([func(*args) for func, args in self.items])

File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 213, in 
item_help = join([func(*args) for func, args in self.items])

File "C:\python\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\argparse.py", line 333, in _format_usage
assert ' '.join(opt_parts) == opt_usage

AssertionError
```

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue.  Special characters in the metavar messes with the `usage` formatting code.  If you really want I could refer you to a relevant bug/issue, but your simplest solution is to not use those characters in the metavar.  Or provide a custom `usage` when defining the parser.  These fancy metavars should still work in the help lines.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. I'll just have to live with it (and hope users use the correct units).

Comment: Usually the usage is more readable if the metavars are simple, e.g.  an upper case abbreviation of the `dest`.  Put details in the help line.